# Get the dates that fall under that week number

Tags: php, date, datetime

So I came up with a situation where I want to retrieve the dates that fall under a specific week number. I tried some methods but unfortunately, they did not work out.

So first I am getting the week number of the date that I have/selected/inputed.

```
$week_number = date('W', strtotime(23/08/2022)) //Will output 34
```

What I tried to do... But the dates that are being returned are random and not what I am expecting

```
$dates = array();
for($i = 1; $i <=7; $i++){
$dates[$i] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($selected_date . ' -' . ($week_number) . ' days +' . 
$i . ' days'));
}
```

What I am expecting:

```
[1] => 2022-08-22
[2] => 2022-08-23
[3] => 2022-08-24
[4] => 2022-08-25
[5] => 2022-08-26
[6] => 2022-08-27
[7] => 2022-08-28
```

I don't know if this is a duplicate question but I cannot find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did something very similar not to long ago. I had to find the date of a day in a week in a certain year. My solution was:

```
function getDateForWeekDay($year, $weekNo, $dayOfWeekNo)
// return the exact date of this weekday, using ISO 8601
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setISODate($year, $weekNo, $dayOfWeekNo);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

for instance, `echo getDateForWeekDay(2020, 34, 1);` will return `2020-08-17`, see: https://3v4l.org/bkjUj

See the PHP manual: [DateTime::setISODate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate)

You can easily expand this to generate your array.

```
for ($day = 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
    $dates[$day] = getDateForWeekDay(2020, 34, $day);
}

print_r($dates);
```

Which returns the wanted result. See: https://3v4l.org/iDKOu

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get monday and sunday of a week :

```
  $day = 1; // 1 to 6, monday to saturday.
  $dayDate = new \DateTime();
  $dayDate->setISODate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('W'), $day);
```